# Getting error no resource found for Xamarin cross platform Project

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am getting below errors as shown in image , tried Below solutions .

1) updated android 6.0 api 23 emulator 
2) Cleaned all the project and rebuild all the project 
3) removed all the nuget packages and updated all the same packages 
But still i am getting below errors,

-Thanks

[[image: Cross platform xamrin - android app using xamarin froms error [1]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Was Xamarin Issue , we cannot do anything with that , some times solution works and sometimes not